# Change background color of <div> tag on button click in Angular 8

Tags: jquery, angular

In below HTML code I am trying to changes the background color of the  on button click.

```html
<div>Hello This is Ajay<\div>

<button>Change Color!<\button>
```

I'm very new to Angular and was trying to connect to JQuery and Angular processes.
Change the background of  is so smooth in JQuery, but its tough with Angular. 
I tried it with @Hostlisteners and HostBinding.
Just wanted to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger a function on button click to change colour. You can toggle between two colours or generate a random one like I did.

```
bgColor : string = 'grey';

changeColor(){
    this.bgColor = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
}
```

And bind the colour value to `div` using `ngStyle`,

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': bgColor}">
    Hello This is Ajay
</div>

<button (click)="changeColor()">Change Color!</button>
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jrx7dz

Comment: It was really Helpful :) Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngClass directive for that purpose using two css classes that will be triggered based on the boolean value of toggle :

template:

```
<button 
    (click)="enableDisableRule()" 
    [ngClass]="{'green' : toggle, 'red': !toggle}">
    {{status}}
</button>
```

css

```
.green {
    background-color: green;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

ts

```
toggle = true;
status = 'Enable'; 

enableDisableRule(job) {
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
    this.status = this.toggle ? 'Enable' : 'Disable';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this code, It works fine. I tested the code on my machine.

HTML Code:

```
 <div [ngClass]=" setRedClass ? 'redClass' : 'blueClass'">
    Some text
 </div>
 <button (click)="toggleClass()">Toggle Class</button>
```

TS Code:

```
 setRedClass: boolean = false;

 toggleClass(){
    this.setRedClass = !this.setRedClass;
 }
```